# Change values after select query

Tags: sql, ms-access

Hello everyone I am having trouble and I can't seem to find an answer that will work for my problem.

I am using Microsoft Access and running a Select query. What I want to then do is change the values in a column for this query.

for example

```
SELECT Table.column1, Table.Column2 
FROM Table
```

I get the following:

```
|Column1|Column2|
    A       1
    B       2
    C       3
    D       2
    E       1
    F       2
    G       3
    H       3
    I       1
    J       2
    K       2
```

I want it so that the query now replaces all the 1s in column2 with 100, all the 2s in column2 with 200 and all the 3s in column2 with 300.

What I dont want to do is update the values in column2  in the original table, I want to change the values just in the query.

Answer (score 2):

If your column2 data are only 1, 2 and 3 you can `multiply` by 100

```
SELECT Table.column1
     , Table.Column2 * 100 as Column2 
FROM Table
```

If your data contains other values than 1,2 and 3 you can use `IIF`

```
SELECT Table.column1
     , IIF(Table.Column2 in (1,2,3),Table.Column2 * 100, Table.Column2) as Column2 
FROM Table
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do calculations in your select queries, e.g.:

```
SELECT Table.column1, Table.Column2 * 100 As Column2
FROM Table
```

This displays the value of `Column2` multiplied by 100, but doesn't modify the underlying table.

You can't modify specific rows just in a query. If you want to modify specific rows, you can just copy the table, or use a make-table query to insert the results of a query in a table and then modify that table.

Answer (score 0):

Other option with `IIF()` :

```
select Col1, iif ( Col2 = 1, 100, 
                   iif ( Col2 = 2, 200, 
                         iif ( Col2 = 3, 300,  col2 ) 
                       ) 
                 ) as col2
from table t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`switch()`](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/switch.php) function:

```
select column1, 
       switch(column2 = 1, 100,
              column2 = 2, 200,
              column2 = 3, 300,
              column2
             ) as new_column2
from t;
```